# Rails associated model's id within a collection's method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given model `Bank` that `has_many` `Account`s. When calling a collection method with the associated bank, how can the bank's ID be retrieved? Or asked differently, what are the variables in the method's scope that relate to an association method called?

For example:

```rb
class Bank
  def do_something_to_accounts
    accounts.do_something
  end
end

class Account
  def self.do_something
    where(name: 'Checking') # this would query against name AND bank_id
    create(name: 'Saving') # this would create an account with name AND bank_id from the associated bank
    # how to determine the bank_id here?
  end
end
```

#### Edit

I noticed there is a method called `scope_attributes` that will show `{bank_id: ID}`

Comment: If you call the account class method, on a bank's account collection, it knows the bank id, because of the collection proxy. If you call it on the Account model itself, then you would need to supply the bank id. It's what active record does under the hood when calling class methods/ scopes on collections v class level. It knows when to auto assign the belongs to id.

Comment: You can just call the method #bank_id on the instance of the Account because it stores that in the DB when you have that association where Bank :has_many Accounts. Make sure you added bank:references to the rails g migration for the Account